# How should I treat a suggested edit to a VLQ question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently surpassed 2,000 reputation and now can review suggested edits (as well as immediately applying any edits to posts). I'm still learning and came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19633723) today.

I rejected the edit as in my view the question is VLQ (could count as unsalvageable... the question was posted two days ago with no answer to the comments from the asker, but I digress...)- it will likely be closed/nuked and therefore there is not much point in editing it.

Reviewing the suggested edit again, admittedly the edit *does* make improvements to the question such as spelling and grammar fixes, and am wondering if I did the right thing by rejecting the edit?

If I see a suggested edit to a low-quality or unsalvageable question, should the edit be evaluated on its own or should the quality of the post as a whole be taken into account?

I realise that I should've probably approved the suggested edit as the edit was approved by another reviewer (making two approvals and one rejection), but would appreciate the input of more experienced reviewers of the Suggested Edit queue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already know the answer.  Turd polishing is not exactly a harmless activity on a web site that has a big content quality problem.  Constantly re-activating the worst posts and letting them crowd out the good stuff can't make anybody happy.  Particularly a problem in the weekend btw.  Pretty unlikely that it can be stopped, this is something the site owners need to fix.

Comment: To expand on @HansPassant's point.  turd polishing is even worse on answers than it is on questions because it clears pending VLQ or NAA flags on those posts.  So the editor may have been trying to help, but instead just made it harder to remove bad content from the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would have rejected that edit as well. It does make a few cosmetic improvements, but does nothing to address the real problems with the post. The OP needs to provide the code that generated that trace and a lot more context before anyone will be reasonably able to answer. I would not want them to see the edit and think that they don't need to make any more improvements.

(I'm torn on the edit to the stack trace. It shouldn't require any more formatting than simple code formatting or quoting, but that edit does make it more readable.)

Answer (score -1):

I would approve that edit.

Everyone looking at that question and wanting to help will either have to wade through horrible formatting, or do what the person doing that edit did first.

That was honest effort, and it *did* make an unreadable bad question into a bad question (which *is a significant improvement*).  As noted, much of the remaining work *could not be done* by an editor; getting it to the stage where the only thing left to do is for the OP to fix the question *is worthwhile*.

And the OP is unlikely to be able to do the formatting fixes.

I'd not only approve that edit, I'd do that edit, and I'd consider a test question where refusing that edit results in a short-term review ban appropriate.